# Image uploads successfully, but browser throws 404 error on android

Tags: php, android

I have a very weird error here, I have successfully uploaded an image in my web server, i mean it shows there, but when i try to open it, it says "The requested URL xxxx was not found on this server". Here is the ss of it:

[image: Image not found]

and here the file is clearly on the server:

[image: web server screenshot]

And here is my Android code in case you need it:

```
public void uploadimage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 1);


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {

    super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);

    if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = I.getData();

        try {

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ImageUploadToServerFunction();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){
    created=false;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStreamObject ;

    byteArrayOutputStreamObject = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStreamObject);

    byte[] byteArrayVar = byteArrayOutputStreamObject.toByteArray();
    long lengthbmp = byteArrayVar.length;
        final String ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar, Base64.DEFAULT);

        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AccountInfoActivity.this, "Image is Uploading", "Please Wait", false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

                super.onPostExecute(string1);

                // Dismiss the progress dialog after done uploading.
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                // Printing uploading success message coming from server on android app.
                Toast.makeText(AccountInfoActivity.this, string1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                // Setting image as transparent after done uploading.


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

                HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

                HashMapParams.put(ImageName, accessSharedPreferences.getFullName(AccountInfoActivity.this)+"-1234567890");

                HashMapParams.put(ImagePath, ConvertImage);

                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(ServerUploadPath, HashMapParams);

                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();

        AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();

}
public class ImageProcessClass {

    public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> PData) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnectionObject;
            OutputStream OutPutStream;
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriterObject;
            BufferedReader bufferedReaderObject;
            int RC;

            url = new URL(requestURL);

            httpURLConnectionObject = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnectionObject.setReadTimeout(19000);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setConnectTimeout(19000);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnectionObject.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setDoOutput(true);

            OutPutStream = httpURLConnectionObject.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriterObject = new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(OutPutStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriterObject.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

            bufferedWriterObject.flush();

            bufferedWriterObject.close();

            OutPutStream.close();

            RC = httpURLConnectionObject.getResponseCode();

            if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReaderObject = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnectionObject.getInputStream()));

                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String RC2;

                while ((RC2 = bufferedReaderObject.readLine()) != null) {

                    stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        StringBuilder stringBuilderObject;

        stringBuilderObject = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {

            if (check)

                check = false;
            else
                stringBuilderObject.append("&");

            stringBuilderObject.append(Uri.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilderObject.append("=");

            stringBuilderObject.append(Uri.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return stringBuilderObject.toString();
    }

}
```

php code for uploading:

```
<?php


// Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect("x.x.x.x", "xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx");

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
 $DefaultId = 0;

 $ImageData = $_POST['image_path'];

 $ImageName = $_POST['image_name'];

 $GetOldIdSQL ="SELECT id FROM UploadImageToServer ORDER BY id ASC";

 $Query = mysqli_query($conn,$GetOldIdSQL);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){

 $DefaultId = $row['id'];
 }

 $ImagePath = "images/$ImageName.jpg";

 $ServerURL = "http://raymartsison.x10host.com/uploads/$ImagePath";

 $InsertSQL = "insert into UploadImageToServer (image_path,image_name) values ('$ServerURL','$ImageName')";

 if(mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL)){

 file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));

 echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
 }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 }else{
 echo "Not Uploaded";
 }

?>
```

I consider it weird because the first file on the screen shot("Aw aw-1234567890.jpg")works perfectly, but others do not. Another reason is when i try to rename or change the extension of those weird files, the error goes away and i am able to open them.
Any help will be very much appreciated.
EDIT:
url of not working image:
http://raymartsison.x10host.com/uploads/images/se%20se-1234567890.jpg

url working(renamed):
http://raymartsison.x10host.com/uploads/images/se%20se-123456789.jpg

Comment: check privilege on file when upload files and when you rename it.

Comment: is it the same as the perms? the perms is the same when uploaded and when i rename it(644), another thing when I rename it back to its original file name, the error once again shows up

Comment: could you update your post with url which is working and not working ?

Comment: ive already updated it , please check the end of my post

Comment: Well, it looks like it's not listed here: http://raymartsison.x10host.com/uploads/images/

Comment: @BBQ,i'm sorry, what do you mean not listed?,as ive said that file exists in my cPanel file manager in that directory,its just that when i try to access it in a web browser, it is saying that the file is not found, which doesnt make sense because i have it in my file manager in first place

Comment: @RaymartSison, In your question, you refer to a screenshot where you point to the image, so it's listed there. Now, browse to the url i've just posted, and you'll see that it isn't listed there, so a webbrowser cant see your image. Therefor it should be a permission issue, or a corrupted image that wont be listed because of that.

Comment: It is in there though, when i click it, the error shows up :(

Comment: So when you browse to: http://raymartsison.x10host.com/uploads/images/, you get both images listed? The one working, and the one not working? Because if you do, it looks like it's more of a cacheing issue, because i clearly can't see that not working image in that indexpage.

Comment: No i just see the one that i recently renamed

Comment: it seems that it is working now, and i think it is  taking some time for it to be "fully?" updated, because i can clearly see the file the i just uploaded, it is not in there and after some time it is now in there, like i told you it is really weird, do you know what's causing this?

Comment: It could be cacheing, so you should try clearing your cache on mobile after uploading that image. It could also mean that your hosting is pretty slow, and needs time to process your upload.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it seems like i still have a long way to go with this cacheing thing, i am using x10hosting, which is a free webhosting site, maybe their servers are pretty slow today, Thanks again!